# Decimation doesn't seem to work even though all requirements are met

Tags: chart.js, decimation

I've been trying everything to get decimation to work in chart.js but don't seem to be able to even though i've met all the requirements mentioned here (at least I think I have): https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/decimation.html.

I've finally gotten around to creating a minimum working example which you can find at the following link. Unforunately even in this example decimation still doesn't work. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-gt7qvw?file=/src/App.js

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd be so grateful, I feel like i've exhausted every avenue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: After a bit more playing, I worked out that decimation only kicks in if you have 4+ times as many points as the pixel width of your chart. I'm not sure why that requirement exists but it seems like it should be documented here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/decimation.html

Comment: Your codesandbox example saved me! Thank you!